# Checking multiple conditions in JavaScript with only if/else statements

Tags: javascript

This is a snippet of my code thus far:

```
    if ((num1 == 3 || num1 == 5  || num1 == 7) && (num2 == 2) && (num3 >= 5 && num3 <= 100) && (num4 < 9 && num4 > 20)) {
      return "correct";
    }else{
      return "incorrect";
     }
   };
```

If I separate each of these conditions they test fine individually, but chained like this they don't. I would really appreciate if someone could explain the best way to do this with only if/else statements. These are the test results:

```
✓ should be defined
✓ should return 'correct' for the correct example
✓ should return 'correct' for all correct first numbers
1) should return 'incorrect' for the incorrect first number example
2) should return 'incorrect' for incorrect second number
✓ should return 'correct' for the boundary conditions of the third number
3) should return 'incorrect' for invalid third numbers
4) should return 'incorrect' for the incorrect fourth number example
5) should return 'incorrect' for the boundary conditions of the fourth number
```

Again, any help would be appreciated, I really want to understand the best approach the this, and exactly whats going on. Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what's happening. What's `num1`, `num2`, etc. could you clarify?

Comment: What's the problem statement? Looks like an online test you're taking. Please link it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I'm new to this. I'll do my best to edit. It's a function that checks four numbers of a code. Num1 should equal 3,5,or 7, num2 should equal 2, num3 should be between 5 and 100, and num4 should be less than 9 and greater than 20. When each condition its tested it will its tests , but when there joined the way I have them they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the

```
...&& (num4 < 9 && num4 > 20)
```

will be false always,

maybe you mean:

```
...&& (num4 < 9 || num4 > 20)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response, it was correct! I don't know how I overlooked that, but I'm learning code does that to you every once in a while...Thanks again!!!